# Emberjs - Accessing a parent inside {{#each}} loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

#### I've searched and searched and I cannot find the solution to the following question:

#### How do you access a parent inside an each loop?

So here's the scenario, I need to pass an id of the parent with the action helper within a nested each loop.

```
{{#each}} {{! iterating the model here (arrayController) }}
    {{#if showingApplicants}} {{! this is set by a button that changes a property inside this particular model object}}
        {{#each applicants}}
            <button {{action addLabel _id}}>Add Label...</button>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I have tried doing `../_id` and `../../_id`. Both of which represent an undefined value. Any clues? **ALSO: Is it possible to pass *two* values in the action helper?**

Comment: is this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tetusada/1/edit what you describe?

Comment: You could set an item controller for both loops and then get the id from the item controller needs...

Comment: @melc That's probably my second choice. In the case that I map an extra data value to contain the IDs, its easier for my API to work with the request to handle the action. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The workaround for this issue was to map out the model data to have an id object that contained the parent id and the child id.

Answer (score 2):

You can create variables on your `#each` blocks so you can refer to them on any context

```
{{#each x in content}}
    {{#if x.showingApplicants}} 
        {{#each applicant in x.applicants}}
            <button {{action addLabel x.id}}>Add Label...</button>
            {{this.controllerProperty}}
            {{x.parentModelProperty}}
            {{y.childModelProperty}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

You could also not name applicant, but if you start by naming the outer context, I would suggest doing it for the nested `each` as well for consistency and to avoid possible name clashes (between the outer variable and child properties).

Hope this helps

Comment: I knew that, but I'm afraid I probably didn't phrase the question right. I needed to pass two ids to the action, which wasn't possible without creating a property via data mapping. I called this object the "ido", and all the actions that handled everything in this particular application took the ido as a param.

Comment: You question was about how to access the parent inside each loop. I think that by doing that it removes the need for the extra property, but the extra property approach would certainly work as well.

Comment: If you could pass 2 parameters in actions, I would agree.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I think this is possible, did you try `{{action addLabel x.id applicant.id}}` according to the documentation, "You can optionally pass arguments to the action handler. Any values passed to the {{action}} helper after the action name will be passed to the handler as arguments." (More: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters)

Comment: I actually did and it did not pass the second value. That's why I resulted to the ido. EDIT: I also noted a lot of issues pertaining to passing multi params to the action helper on the ember repo. I didn't read into them, but it's possible that it could have been changed recently.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for the extra details. I just looked into it and it seems to be working fine on handlebars and ember 1.0.0 AND the latest versions. Have a look at http://jsbin.com/dokuy/1/edit

Comment: Also, make sure you didn't have a comma to split between the parameters, that's the intuitive think to do in JS, but it's not valid handlebars

Comment: I didn't, but like I said I think I have an old version of handlebars.

Comment: That would explain it, sorry, I didn't see any comment about the version of handlebars

Comment: "I also noted a lot of issues pertaining to passing multi params to the action helper on the ember repo. I didn't read into them, but it's possible that it could have been changed recently." No problem. Might have been vague.